# EF6 specify order of tables in Migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first

In my database I have a couple tables with multiple PKs, which are each FKs.
Below is the C# definition of one such Entity:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Represents a permission record in the client database.
/// Contains information on which <see cref="User"/> has access to which <see cref="Company"/> and which <see cref="Module"/>.
/// </summary>
public class Permission
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the unique identifier of the <see cref="User"/> to which the <see cref="Permission"/> is linked.
    /// </summary>
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the unique identifier of the <see cref="Company"/> to which the <see cref="Permission"/> is linked.
    /// </summary>
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the unique identifier of the <see cref="Module"/> to which the <see cref="Permission"/> is linked.
    /// </summary>
    public Guid ModuleId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the date and time at which the <see cref="Permission"/> was created.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; } = DateTime.UtcNow;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the date and time at which the <see cref="Permission"/> was last updated.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; } = DateTime.UtcNow;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a concurrency token used to prevent conflicting edits in a <see cref="Permission"/> entity.
    /// </summary>
    [SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "AutoPropertyCanBeMadeGetOnly.Global", Justification = "Used by Entity Framework.")]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; } = null!;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the <see cref="User"/> to which the <see cref="Permission"/> is linked through <see cref="UserId"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public User User { get; set; } = null!;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the <see cref="Company"/> to which the <see cref="Permission"/> is linked through <see cref="CompanyId"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public Company Company { get; set; } = null!;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the <see cref="Module"/> linked to the <see cref="Permission"/> through <see cref="ModuleId"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public Module Module { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

The FluentAPI configuration for the Permission entity is as below:

```cs
public class PermissionConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Permission>
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Permission> builder)
    {
        builder = builder ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));

        builder.HasKey(permission => new
        {
            permission.UserId,
            permission.CompanyId,
            permission.ModuleId,
        });

        builder.Property(p => p.CreatedAt)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()")
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(p => p.UpdatedAt)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()")
            .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(p => p.RowVersion)
            .IsRowVersion();

        // Configures one-to-many FK relationship with User table.
        builder.HasOne(p => p.User)
            .WithMany(u => u.Permissions)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade) // deletions are handled by context instead of SQL behaviour.
            .IsRequired();

        // Configures one-to-many FK relationship with Company table.
        builder.HasOne(p => p.Company)
            .WithMany(c => c.Permissions)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.CompanyId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade) // deletions are handled by context instead of SQL behaviour.
            .IsRequired();

        // Configures one-to-many FK relationship with Module table.
        builder.HasOne(p => p.Module)
            .WithMany(m => m.Permissions)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.ModuleId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade) // deletions are handled by context instead of SQL behaviour.
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

Every time I apply a new migration, Entity Framework crashes on a FK exception.
At first I figured to set the `ON DELETE` behaviour for the Permission entity to `ClientCascade`, so that the context would handle deleting the records.

This has however not fixed it, and it seems the real problem is that EF tries to truncate the rows from either the User, Company or Module tables before getting to the Permission table.
I figured this would not be a new problem and the use case does not seem very far fetched to me, however I have not been able to find a solution to this.

Is there a way to specify an order in which tables are truncated in the `Down` method of migrations?
I would assume instructing EF to first empty the Permission table before the Company, User and Module tables would solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why row is deleted?

Comment: Not deleted as such, I should clarify I'm talking about the order of the tables in the `Down` methods of migrations. Will update the question

Comment: Why rows are truncated?

Comment: Whatever the migration creator comes up with, you can freely modify the code, swap the order of specific statements etc. It's your migration, the generated code is just a sketch, good in most cases, editable in specific cases.